# Cannot add data to PHP array in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, indexing

I have a PHP array, actually a MySQL row constructed with CodeIgniter's Active Record.

So I have an array which var_dumps like this :

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'puzzle_id' => string '17' (length=2)
      'birth' => string '2014-01-26 16:08:25' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'puzzle_id' => string '16' (length=2)
      'birth' => string '2014-01-26 02:07:05' (length=19)
  2 => .....
```

this is constructed like this :

```
$this->db->order_by("birth" , "desc");
$rows = $this->db->get("my_table" , $limit)->result_array();        
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $row['testindex'] = "testvalue";
}
return $rows;
```

so why does my array NOT have the "testindex" indices ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not how PHP and `foreach()` in particular works.

`$row` in your code is a copy of the corresponding element in `$rows`, not the actual element. Modifying a copy doesn't modify the original.

You'd want to do this:

```
for ($i = 0, $c = count($rows); $i < $c; $i++)
{
    $rows[$i]['testindex'] = 'testvalue';
}
```

Comment: Wow, I always thought that foreach implicitly does that for me. Thanks for your answer! It both solved my problem, and tought me how to catch a fish :) Accepting in few minutes.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw If this solution solves your problem, then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (PHP 5+):

```
foreach($rows as &$row)
{
    $row['testindex'] = "testvalue";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my web server has an older PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can do this with `foreach` too.

Like this :

```
foreach($rows as $key => $value)
{
  $rows[$key]['testindex'] = "testvalue";
}
```

Comment: Yes, you could. But `$value` is something you don't need here.

Comment: You are right, however, there are two unnecessary variables `$i` and `$c` in the for loop. And I like the look of a foreach better. Less code and more readability. Thanks for your answer though !

Comment: They are not unnecessary. :)

Comment: Neither is $value , since it allows me to write shorter and prettier code :)

Comment: That's where you're wrong. :) Anyway, I'm not here to argue with you ... if that's what you want to use - it's your choice.